# statistics of aggregated random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose $X \in {\cal N}(\mu,B)$ is a multivariate Gaussian random variable.

Furthermore, let $x^k$, with $k=1\ldots K$ be samples drawn from this distribution, with each sample $x^k \in \mathbb{R}^N$.

Now, suppose we want to estimate the mean and standard deviation of the random variable $Y := \sum_{l=i}^j X_l$ from the sample defined above, for some $1<i<j<N$. I proceed to calculate $y_k:= \sum_{l=i}^j x^k_l$ for all $k$, and use the standard (scalar) formulas to get the mean $\bar{y^k}$ and standard deviation $\sigma_{y^k}$ of these $K$ values.

My question is: *will $( \bar{y^k}, \sigma_{y^k} )$ approximate well the "true" mean/standard deviation of $Y$, at least for large enough $K$?*  The answer below says *yes*.

I have run a small numerical experiment (using Python) to test the quality of the approximation:

1. for all $k = 1\ldots K$: draw samples $x_k \sim {\cal N}(\mu,B)$.
2. for all $k = 1\ldots K$: $y^k := \sum_{l=i}^{j} x^k_{l}$. These are scalar quantities, so we can write $y^k := A x^k$, with 
   $$
    A := [0 \ldots 0 \, \underbrace{1 \ldots 1}_{ i \ldots j } \, 0 \ldots 0] \in \mathbb{R}^{1\times N}
   $$
3. $\bar{y^k} := \frac{1}{K} \sum_k y^k$ and ${\rm var}(y^k) := \frac{1}{K-1} \sum_k (y^k - \bar{y^k})^2$.
4. $
   {\rm var}(Y) 
   = \sum_{l=i}^{j} {\rm var}(X_l) + 2 \sum_{l=i}^{j} \sum_{p>l}^{j} \, {\rm cov}(X_i,X_j)
   = \sum_{l=i}^{j} B_{ll} + 2 \sum_{l=i}^{j} \sum_{p>l}^{j} B_{lp}
   $
5. compare ${\rm var}(Y)$ against ${\rm var}(y^k)$.

Observed outcome: ${\rm var}(y^k) \approx {\rm var}(Y)$ (as I increase $K$, the agreement gets better).

Comment: What makes you say "I have run a small numerical experiment and it seems that the answer is *no*"?

Comment: I'll edit my question to expand on this. The answer of @filipos makes perfect sense, so there must be something wrong with my numerical test case...

Comment: There must be something wrong with your code. Can you post it?

Comment: @filipos Yes, sure enough, there was a bug in my code. it's been fixed now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Y$ is a regular normal variable, and your procedure is equivalent to sampling it $K$ times and applying the usual estimates.

The result will have the same quality that you are used to for estimating any normal random variable from $K$ samples. In particular, it will approximate well the true parameters for large $K$.

In fact, it is easy to verify that the result is exactly equivalent to estimating the multivariate parameters and deriving the parameters for $Y$ from them, so you are not losing any information.

To see that, write $Y = AX$, where $A$ is any linear transformation. Let $y^k = Ax^k$ be the corresponding samples for $Y$. Estimating $X$ we get

$$\widehat{\mu}_X = \frac{1}{K}\sum_{k=1}^K x^k$$
$$\widehat{B}_X = \frac{1}{K}\sum_{k=1}^K (x^k-\widehat{\mu}_X)(x^k-\widehat{\mu}_X)^T$$

The corresponding parameters for $Y$ would be $A\widehat{\mu}_X$ and $A\widehat{B}_X A^T$.

Estimating $Y$ directly we get exactly that:

$$\widehat{\mu}_Y = \frac{1}{K}\sum_{k=1}^K y^k = \frac{1}{K}\sum_{k=1}^K Ax^k = A\widehat{\mu}_X$$

$$\widehat{B}_Y = \frac{1}{K}\sum_{k=1}^K (y^k-\widehat{\mu}_Y)(y^k-\widehat{\mu}_Y)^T = \frac{1}{K}\sum_{k=1}^K (Ax^k-A\widehat{\mu}_X)(Ax^k-A\widehat{\mu}_X)^T = A\widehat{B}_XA^T$$

Comment: Thank you, very neat answer. This observation should generalize to non-normal random variables as well, right? (as long as the mapping $A$ is linear)

Comment: @mishooax I do not see an obvious generalisation. For instance, if $X = (X_1, X_2)$ with $X_2 = X_1$ and $A(x_1,x_2) = x_1$, then the estimates will not be equivalent.